# Probability distribution for a given variable and frequency

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

[image]

I need to construct a probability distribution for the given table. I am quite unsure where to start.

I tried plotting $x$ and $p(x)$ where $x$ is the number of $2$-pound fresh lobster dinner platters ordered during the evening and $p(x)$ is the frequency # of evenings divided by the total frequency of that column (i.e: $50$)

However, this resulted in a plot that looked off, especially for a probability distribution.

I'd appreciate any advice with regards to solving this, I am properly stumped!

Comment: Based on the data, the best fit would just be
$$
p(x) =\begin{cases}
\frac{11}{25},& x=12\\
\frac6{25},& x=14\\
\frac4{25},& x=16\\
\frac3{25},& x=18\\
\frac1{25},& x=20.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: What you described sounds exactly correct. Why exactly did you think it was wrong? "Especially for a probability distribution"? Strictly speaking, since this is a discrete distribution, the main condition it needs to satisfy is that the the sum of all the $p(x)$ values has to be $1.$

Comment: The one thing that is particularly fishy (pardon the pun) about these figures is that there is never a night when an odd number of orders is placed. I mean, 22 times they serve 12 platters, 12 times they serve 14 platters, but never once do they ever serve 13 platters, or 11, or 15? But that's what the data say, so it would be wrong for you _not_ to have those gaps in your distribution.

Comment: Turns out after conversing with my tutor, I believe I am actually right and was just confusing a probability distribution with a normal probability distribution and thinking hey this isn't bell curved so it must be wrong. I'll post the apparent solution soon :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I was just overthinking my solution, and after consulting my tutor, it appears that I am on the right track.

Thanks for the feedback.

Here is the apparent solution: